# seleccionar datos de dos tablas sin relacion mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy creando un formulario para actualizar datos, traigo la información de la tabla `escolar` llamada **T1** para actualizarla, y de otra tabla `ge_jornada` llamada **T2** que no tiene relación con T1, genero de nuevo las opciones para un dropdown, el cual ya muestra la jornada guardada, y debe mostrar las opciones alternativas que están en **T2**.

Tabla 1 = escolar = T1

```
id | alumno | acudiente | direccion | tarifa  | placa  | jornada |
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | juan   | Maria     | Calle 107 | $80.000 | TTY521 | A       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
 2 | pablo  | Lina      | Calle 47  | $90.000 | TTY521 | B       |
```

Tabla 2 = ge_jornada = T2 esta tabla es para construir el dropdown

```
id | jornada |
--------------
 1 | A       |
--------------
 2 | B       |
--------------
 3 | Unica   |
```

estoy tratando de obtener los datos asi:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("*****", "user", "***", "BD") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
    $query_edit = "SELECT t1.* FROM escolar as t1 WHERE t1.id='$editid' AND t1.placa = '$placa_id'
    CROSS JOIN    SELECT t2.jornada AS jos FROM ge_jornada as t2";

    $edit = mysqli_query( $con, $query_edit );
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($edit);
```

Mi formulario PHP para actualizar

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="actualizar.php" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" placeholder="Direccion" value="<?php echo $row['t1.direccion']; ?>" required>

<select id="jornada"  class="js-select js-select-3" name="jornada" required>
<option value="<?php echo $row['t1.jornada']; ?>"><?php echo $row['t1.jornada']; ?></option>

<?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($edit)) {
echo '<option value='.$row["t1.id"].'>'.$row["t2.jos"].'</option>';
}  mysqli_free_result($edit) ?>    
</select>
...
```

Pero no consigo que me traiga la informacion para actualizar, no carga ningun dato.

Gracias por la ayuda soy aprendiz.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es del todo claro y por lo tanto se hace difícil darte una respuesta adecuada. No se entiende si llenas dropdown de las tablas y luego tomas algunos datos de esos dropdown para hacer la actualización. No expliques las cosas en genérico: *actualizar datos*... si dices actualizar tales datos de tal tabla, eso ayuda a la comprensión del problema... *la tabla que voy a actualizar* ... ¿qué tabla, cómo se llama? ... *y de otra tabla* ... sí, pero ¿cómo se llama esa otra tabla, por qué la incluyes, vas a usar datos de ella para el `UPDATE`, qué datos?

Comment: comprendo, ya edito la pregunta

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la estructura de las tablas?

Comment: ¿Que buscas devolver en el combo ?

Comment: Ahora si tiene sentido jaja, pero,¿Para que quieres unir los datos si ambos datos ya están en la tabla T1 ?

Comment: en el dropdown busco que muestre la jornada guardada en la tabla1 del usuario seleccionado, y brindar las otras opciones de la tabla 2

Comment: es que en la tabla 1 esta solo la informacion por cada usuario y la 2 tiene las opciones independientes del dropdown cuando se agrega un nuevo registro, y al darle modificar debo mostrar la opcion guardada, y brindar las alternativas

Comment: Per-fec-to podrias añadirlo a la pregunta, asi no se pierde en el comentario.

Comment: Andrés ¿tú suponías que nosotros sabíamos todo lo que has dicho posteriormente y lo que dices en los comentarios?  Nosotros no sabemos absolutamente nada de lo que hace tu programa. Explica las cosas con toda claridad y podremos decirte: ¿por qué haces esto así si de este otro modo es mejor?... etc Si eres lo más claro posible el único beneficiado eres tú. Expón con todo detalle el problema, tampoco cuesta tanto. En uno o dos párrafos se dice lo que hace un programa y se explica un problema concreto con ese programa.

Comment: Si lo siento tenes toda la razon, apenas aprendiendo del tema y todo esto me sirve para ampliar los conocimientos muchas gracias por tus comentarios.

Comment: Por ejemplo, expones que quieres actualizar la tabla (al fin llamaste la tabla por su nombre... bien por ti), pero si leemos la pregunta no vemos **con qué datos quieres actualizar esa tabla**. ¿Quizá sea esa la clave para resolver tu problema y ni siquiera la mencionas? Además, ¿esa actualización debe cumplir algún criterio... qué criterio..., debe actualizar un sólo registro, varios registros, todos los registros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas hacerlo todo en un query.  Puedes hacer dos queries separadas y luego setear el valor del select asi:

```
$query_edit = "SELECT * FROM escolar WHERE id='$editid' AND placa = '$placa_id'";
$query2 = "SELECT jornada FROM ge_jornada";

$edit = mysqli_query( $con, $query_edit );
$edit2 = mysqli_query( $con, $query2 );
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($edit);

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="actualizar.php" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" placeholder="Direccion" value="<?php echo $row['direccion']; ?>" required>

<select id="jornada"  class="js-select js-select-3" name="jornada" required>

<?php while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($edit2)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row2["id"].'"' . ($row['jornada'] == $row2['jornada'] ? ' selected' : '') .'>'.$row2["jornada"].'</option>';
}  mysqli_free_result($edit) ?>    
</select>
```

Comment: Hola, acabe de intenterlo, pero me sigue mostrando los campos vacios para actualizarlos

Comment: Ya edite.  Me parece que los nombres de las columnas no tienen que llevar el nombre de la tabla.  Intentalo asi.

Comment: Hola ya actualice mi pregunta, pero aun no consigo que me traiga los datos, sera problema de mi servidor, estoy udando ipage.com

Comment: Creo que ya entendi lo que quieres hacer.  Ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Alan yo estoy usando `$row = mysqli_fetch_row($edit);` porque vi en un tutorial esa secuencia, yo estoy usandolo, y no consigo traer los datos de la BD, hice tal cual lo pusiste y lo veo muy bien pero no consigo llamar los datos, y la conexion esta bn, es mas actualizo esa parte.

Comment: Intenta con `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Alan muchisimas gracias funciono perfectamente, y gracias a todos los demas. :)

Comment: De nada @AndresArango, y coincido con los demas, en tu proxima pregunta, trata de ser un poco mas claro.